# VBScript - Modify Windows Env Variables

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

I currently use a batch file to override some environment variables to make a game portable.

Mainly the below:

```
Set USERPROFILE = %CD%
```

This only stays in effect through that session or through a program loaded  from the batch. So when I load the game through it with:

```
Start "" "FL.exe"
```

The game treats the My Documents, My Pictures and AppData folders as being within my game folder.

Can this functionality be replicated within VBScript at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, through the [`WshShell.Environment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd7hxfdd(v=vs.84).aspx) object. You can query, add, and remove environmental variables at the system, user, and process level.

For example:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objProcessVars = objShell.Environment("process")

' Query existing environmental variables...
For Each objVar In objProcessVars
    WScript.Echo objVar
Next

' Add/Override a process-level variable...
objProcessVars("USERPROFILE") = "C:\Test"

' Spawned processes inherit your process-level variables...
objShell.Run "C:\AnotherScript.vbs"

' When script terminates, changes are lost.
```

Comment: Does that function perform exactly the same as in my initial question? Temporary? Passing to any EXE loaded by the VBScript?

Comment: Yes. Any processes spawned by your VBScript will inherit the process-level environmental variables. And when your script terminates, any changes to process-level variables will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful :)